# KASAN & KCOV kernel extensions are unsigned? is this normal?

Tags: macos, ventura, kernel-extensions, code-signing

While trying to find an issue with my computer, I was going through my kexts on profiler and Kasan.kext and Kcov.kext appear to have both been unsigned and recently modified. This had me wondering if this is normal or not.

I'm running macOS Ventura (13.4)
[image]

Comment: Are [KASAN](http://google.github.io/kernel-sanitizers/KASAN.html) and [XCOV](https://github.com/fastlane-community/xcov) installed on your Mac?

Comment: apologies, it was Kcov, not Xcov - Kasan is probably the same that you mention, but apple's implementation. But neither was installed by me; my guess is that they were part of ventura/xcode, or I somehow agreed to have them installed. What bugs me is that since they are supposedly made by apple, why are they unsigned?